# Are {$a {\cdot} b\ \ |\ \ a \in A, b \in B$} and {$a {\cdot} b\ \ |\ \ (a, b) \in A \times B$} the same thing?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Given two sets $A$ and $B$ are the following two sets equivalent?

- {$a {\cdot} b\ \ |\ \ a \in A, b \in B$}, and
- {$a {\cdot} b\ \ |\ \ (a, b) \in A \times B$}

Comment: Have you tried just showing set inclusion in both directions?

Comment: Yes, they are.  The first is the set of all products where the first is an element of A and the second is an element of B.  The second is the of all products where the terms come from an ordered pairs and the first term is from A and the second term is from B.  Those are the same results.

Comment: I think Micheal Morrows comment is overkill but it's good practice.  If $k \in$ the first set then there exists an $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ so that $k = a\cdot b$.  But as $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $c=(a,b)\in A\times B$.  So there exists $(a,b)\in A\times B$ where $k=a\cdot b$.  So $k\in$ the second set.  So the first set is a subset of the second.  You can do the same for the other direction pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
The Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$ is the set of 2-tupples generated by pairing all elements of $A$ with all elements of $B$. Or

$A\times B = \{ (a,b) | a\in A, b \in B\}$

As there are no restrictions on $A$ and $B$ in your first set it is equivalent to your second set.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @amWhy If you read the OP you will see that the question is not about whether the defined set is a subset of $A\times B$ but is about whether the definition of the two sets is equivalent. The original response addressed this point by answering, correctly, that the two definitions are equivalent (feel free to prove this yourself). You are correct that the OPs set is not a subset of $A\times B$, however, there was no comment or assertion to that point as I addressed the OPs question. So I am changing the answer back to the, correct, affirmative answer.